# How do I prepare for a meeting with a senior manager about a conflict with my manager?

Tags: management, salary, conflict, quitting

I have spent all my professional life working as developer (not very long, like 5 years) and during that time I have been a hard working person (or at least I consider myself). My previous boss and I decided to move on and start a new business a year and half ago. Since starting I normally work 12 hours a day and about 8 on weekends. My schedule is only to work 9 hours a day but I'm working all the time. We kind of have a friendship but  we had a fight as he wanted to change the TV at lunch time while I was watching a soccer game. This was not during working hours and the TV is not owned by the company. The fight turned physical when he pushed me and insulted me. The problem now that my salary has been cut and I was removed as the manager of some of the areas I was running previous to this.

The general manager knew about the conflict and set us for a meeting today but I don’t know if is a good idea.  How should I approach preparing for this meeting?

Comment: If a fight over the show playing on a television at lunch time on the weekend almost got physical, and as a result he demoted you and gave you a pay cut, I would definitely be looking for employment elsewhere.  However, until you have another job it is probably best to play nice.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to The Workplace. I'm sorry this happened to  you but what is your question here? This has received downvotes and was closed because it reads like a big rant and you don't really have a question which can be answered. Are you asking, "should I quit?" - if so, these sorts of questions are generally off topic as per the [FAQ].

Comment: I have edited the question to make it about how should you prepare for the meeting with your senior manager since that is the only constructive thing I could see to ask.  If that is not the question you want answered then I suggest you either edit the question after reading the [FAQ] or delete the question entirely.  I think focusing your energy here right now is probably the best thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 14):

As per the above description I understand you guys argued seriously and emotions rampup so quickly and it lead to unprofessional behaviour. I can not assess whose side is mistake. But in order to prepare for meeting below points will helpful

When conflict occurs at workplace, always the objective would be resolve the conflict and avoid such conflicts in future. Otherwise it impacts everyone, you, your boss and project badly. So first target to resolve conflict somehow. Basically here your senior manager trying to resolve the conflict here. From your side you have to take care of the below things.

**Represent only facts with all the details:** Please tell the facts only and not your opinions, feelings and assumptions. Be accurate and clear.

**Don't make personal comments:** Don't make personal comments like he is arrogant and can not be controllable etc.. Describe his behaviour and express your concerns and how you feel about his behaviour.

**Show attitude towards resolving the conflict:** Tell him that you really want to resolve this conflict and avoid these kind of conflicts further. Show readiness to correct if there is any mistake on your part.

**Accept your part of the mistake if any**: I always believe if conflicts occurs between 2 parties, both the parties are contributing some of the other to that conflict. It is myth that only one person contributes 100% to the conflict. Now realize your part to that conflict and accept it.

**Don't spread this to others on your own:** Don't spread this news to others in the organization. It adds the fuel to the conflict and adds complexity to the situation.

**Discuss about the impact and alternate plan**: Explain the manager the impact that you faced due to this conflict and also check with him what are the options that you have if the conflict can not be resolved.